# Job doesn't reschedule immediately when triggers update in quartz

Tags: spring, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to develop an spring application using Quartz which reads trigger time for Job from database and run it. I have managed to implement this scenario successfully.However, during job execution when i update the trigger time in database, it doesn't run the trigger the job according to the new time but it always run old time.

Code:

```
@Configuration 
@ComponentScan
public class QuartzConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean methodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean() {
        MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean obj = new MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean();
        obj.setTargetBeanName("jobone");
        obj.setTargetMethod("myTask");
        return obj;
    }
    @Autowired
    public TestModelRepository testModelRepository;


    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean(){
        JobDetailFactoryBean factory = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factory.setJobClass(MyJobTwo.class);
        TestModel result = testModelRepository.findOne((long) 1);
        factory.setGroup("mygroup");
        factory.setName("myjob");
        return factory;
    }
    public TestModelRepository getTestModelRepository() {
        return testModelRepository;
    }
    public void setTestModelRepository(TestModelRepository testModelRepository) {
        this.testModelRepository = testModelRepository;
    }
    @Bean
    public CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean(){

        CronTriggerFactoryBean stFactory = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        stFactory.setJobDetail(jobDetailFactoryBean().getObject());
        //stFactory.setStartDelay(3000;
        stFactory.setName("mytrigger");
        stFactory.setGroup("mygroup");
         TestModel result = testModelRepository.findOne((long) 1);

        stFactory.setCronExpression(result.getCronTime());
        return stFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {

        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(cronTriggerFactoryBean().getObject());



        return scheduler;
    }
```

}

**Job:**

```
@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class MyJobTwo extends QuartzJobBean {
    public static final String COUNT = "count";
    private static URI jiraServerUri = URI.create("");
    JiraRestClient restClient = null;
    private String name;
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {


             final AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory factory = new AsynchronousJiraRestClientFactory();
                restClient = factory.createWithBasicHttpAuthentication(jiraServerUri,"", "");


        }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: Reload configuration or if you are using spring-boot for reboot.

Comment: how to reload configuration?

Comment: It's very easy you need to use a classloader.

Comment: i'm not getting you. any example?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if someone needs solution.

```
SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
scheduler.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
```